# C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?

Tags: c#, reflection, generic-list

I'm working on a reflection project, and now I'm stuck.

If I have an object of `myclass` that can hold a `List<SomeClass>`, does anyone know how to get the type as in the code below if the property `myclass.SomList` is empty?

```
List<myclass> myList = dataGenerator.getMyClasses();
lbxObjects.ItemsSource = myList; 
lbxObjects.SelectionChanged += lbxObjects_SelectionChanged;

private void lbxObjects_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Reflect();
}

Private void Reflect()
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in lbxObjects.SelectedItem.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        switch (pi.PropertyType.Name.ToLower())
        {
            case "list`1":
            {           
                // This works if the List<T> contains one or more elements.
                Type tTemp = GetGenericType(pi.GetValue(lbxObjects.SelectedItem, null));

                // but how is it possible to get the Type if the value is null? 
                // I need to be able to create a new object of the type the generic list expect. 
                // Type type = pi.getType?? // how to get the Type of the class inside List<T>?
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private Type GetGenericType(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        Type t = obj.GetType();
        if (t.IsGenericType)
        {
            Type[] at = t.GetGenericArguments();
            t = at.First<Type>();
        } 
        return t;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 286, accepted):

```
Type type = pi.PropertyType;
if(type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        == typeof(List<>))
{
    Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // use this...
}
```

---

More generally, to support any `IList<T>`, you need to check the interfaces:

```
foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
{
    if (interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
        interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
        == typeof(IList<>))
    {
        Type itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        // do something...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be Type itemType = interfaceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];

Comment: Amusingly, the second example fails with, say `IList<int>`. Fix below http://stackoverflow.com/a/13608408/284795

Comment: I know that the answer is very old, but I try to understand the following: 'GetGenericArguments()[0];' why is there the 0? Is there only always one item in the Type[] ?

Comment: Because the call GetGenericArguments() returns an array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments(v=vs.110).aspx
A List will only have one type. A dictionary would have two for example.

Answer (score 24):

*Given an object which I suspect to be some kind of `IList<>`, how can I determine **of what** it's an `IList<>`?*

Here's the gutsy solution. It assumes you have the actual object to test (rather than a `Type`).

```
public static Type ListOfWhat(Object list)
{
    return ListOfWhat2((dynamic)list);
}

private static Type ListOfWhat2<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    return typeof(T);
}
```

Example usage:

```
object value = new ObservableCollection<DateTime>();
ListOfWhat(value).Dump();
```

Prints

```
typeof(DateTime)
```

Comment: -1: Why `IList<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`? Why `dynamic`?

Comment: Did I misunderstand OP's question? The detail was unclear, so I answered the question in the title.

Comment: You sir, are a Wizard!  I have been banging my head trying to solve an issue with a dynamic parser with a generic data structure (that can deal with singular types and Lists) and *this* got me on the right track.

Comment: Great example of 'dynamic' usage

Answer (score 12):

Marc's answer is the approach I use for this, but for simplicity (and a friendlier API?) you can define a property in the collection base class if you have one such as:

```
public abstract class CollectionBase<T> : IList<T>
{
   ...

   public Type ElementType
   {
      get
      {
         return typeof(T);
      }
   }
}
```

I have found this approach useful, and is easy to understand for any newcomers to generics.

Comment: I wanted to use this approach but then i realized i will have to have the list instance in order to determine element type, which i will not always have.

Comment: you can make the property static. Like "public static Type ElementType" ... then you get at it as "var t = CollectionBase<int>.ElementType;" ... you will not need an instance variable

Comment: True. Static allows you to work with a class without an existing object. I find this approach easier to work with. Sure, you need to store additional information in your objects but at least you spare yourself from this cascade-call in the approved answer.

Answer (score 10):

*Given an object which I suspect to be some kind of `IList<>`, how can I determine **of what** it's an `IList<>`?*

Here's a reliable solution. My apologies for length - C#'s introspection API makes this suprisingly difficult.

```
/// <summary>
/// Test if a type implements IList of T, and if so, determine T.
/// </summary>
public static bool TryListOfWhat(Type type, out Type innerType)
{
    Contract.Requires(type != null);

    var interfaceTest = new Func<Type, Type>(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>) ? i.GetGenericArguments().Single() : null);

    innerType = interfaceTest(type);
    if (innerType != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    foreach (var i in type.GetInterfaces())
    {
        innerType = interfaceTest(i);
        if (innerType != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example usage:

```
    object value = new ObservableCollection<int>();
Type innerType;
TryListOfWhat(value.GetType(), out innerType).Dump();
innerType.Dump();
```

Returns

```
True
typeof(Int32)
```

Comment: I don't see any other result as Marcs method (also with marcs i get Int32)