# How to detect if a type is a Func<T> and get the type of the T

Tags: c#, generics, ioc-container

I am wondering whether I can upgrade a basic IoC container I am using to support lazy load.
So if I have registered IFoo, I would like the IoC container to know how to fulfil both of the following dependencies (the first being the standard way IoC containers work, while the second returns a simple delegate that calls into the container for an IFoo when it is invoked).

```
public Bar(IFoo x)

public Bar2(Func<IFoo> lazyFoo)
```

The problem comes when I try to write the code that will actually do this. Is there a syntax that will make the following pseudo-code compile?

```
public T Resolve<T>()
{
    if (T is Func<X>)
        return (T) () => Resolve(typeof(X));
    return (T)Resolve(typeof(T));
}
```

Or to put my question another way, if I have a type `T`, how can I detect if it is an instance of `Func<X>`, and if so, what is the type of `X`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at this question from this morning - might give you a good start - [C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Comment: Indeed, replace `List` with `Func` and you're done...

Comment: yes, looks like this will do it for me. thanks
Now I have a problem that the compiler won't let me cast from
() => Resolve(theArgumentType) back to the original T (even if I try to cast to object first). "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'T' because it is not a delegate type"

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood your question.

It is impossible to do it in one function the way you're trying to because the compiler must have a delegate type to create the lambda as at compile time.

However, this should work.

```
public T Resolve<T>()
{
    return (T)Resolve(typeof(T));
}

public Func<T> LazyResolve<T>()
{
    return () => Resolve<T>();
}
```

Comment: ok I think I understand why its not possible. Shame, because it would be a nice feature for an IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question in the comment, you need to invoke the lambda expression, not cast it.

Comment: I don't want to invoke it yet, I want to pass the Func itself back so that the caller can invoke it when they are ready to

Comment: Then you need to cast it to Func<T>.

Comment: I misunderstood; see second answer.