# How to get string type for nullable types

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm generating a T4 template using the properties of my data class generated from my dbml files. To get the property type of the classes I use `item.PropertyType.Name`, the problem is that with nullable types it returns `Nullable` ``1`, is there a way to get`Nullable`for example, or`int?`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GetGenericArguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) is the method you want.

```
if (item.PropertyType.IsGenericType) {
    if (item.PropertyType.GetGenericType() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {
        var valueType = item.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

On second thought though, Darren's answer is much simpler in this case as it will return null when you pass in a non-nullable type.

Answer (score 11):

`int?` === `Nullable<int>`. they are one in the same. If you want to know that what type the nullable is, then you can use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(int?))` method to get the type (in this instance `int`)

[Nullable.GetUnderlyingType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t).  Marc Gravell's answer there will tell you how to get the type of the generic arguments.