# Return List<T> generic type

Tags: c#, list, reflection, types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Lets say I have a `List<Stock>` given `typeof(List<Stock>)` how do I determine what the type is for the generic list? IE: In this case Stock?

Looking at the Type information I can see the `AssemblyQualifiedName` provides this to some degree

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[FullQualifiedName.Stock,
>   TestApp, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]], mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

but I'm wondering if I can actually return the Type of the generic Type for the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var innerType = typeof(List<Stock>).GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

In this case `innerType == typeof(Stock)`

Answer (score 0):

You can call `.GetGenericArguments()` on the type. This will return an array of types.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx