# Finding <T> in IList<T> using reflection

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm working on a project where I have to reflect through data models to find out what type is in each property on a data models.  I have the code working for all cases except for generic collections. I have to be able to what T is in IList.

I have the following data model

```
public class ArrryOfObjects
{
    public NestModelNestedClass NestClass { get; set; }
    public int IntObject { get; set; }
    public IList<NestModelNestedClass> ListOfObjects { get; set; }
}
```

I've seen a couple of examples, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043778/136717 on how to do this, but they use the `type.GetGenericTypeDefinition()` to be get the type.  But in my sample I cannot use this because 'type.IsGeneric.Parameter' is false.

I've review Type documentation and don't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var t = typeof(ArrryOfObjects)
    .GetProperty("ListOfObjects")
    .PropertyType
    .GetGenericArguments()[0];
```

This is how it works:

- From the type of `ArrryOfObjects`...
- obtain the property called `ListOfObjects`...
- get the type of that property...
- which we know to be a generic type with at least one type parameter.
- We get the first type parameter - in your example it should be `typeof(NestModelNestedClass)`

P.S. `GetGenericTypeDefinition` gets you `typeof(IList<>)`, the generic type of which `IList<NestModelNestedClass>` is a generic instance.

Comment: Thanks.  My actual code was basically same as yours, except of [0] on GetGenericArguements().