# Getting a List(T) from a string representation of a type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a string representation of a type, and I need to get a list of that specific type. I am trying this:

```
var string_rep = "Double";
var list = _context.Entity.ToList<Type.GetType(string_rep)>();
```

I am getting "Operator < cannot be applied to operands of type method group and System.Type". What's the right way of doing it? Appreciate it.

Comment: The resulting type cannot be expressed at compile-time; your variable will be mostly useless.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you really want to do this, you need to use reflection to hit the correct method (which will be a static ToList method in the Queryable class, since it is an extension method) - but read Servy's answer first.

Comment: You are trying to give it a runtime evaluate Type class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there's no way of typing the `list` variable to the actual generic type of the list if that type isn't known until runtime, there's no real benefit to having the list strongly typed to begin with.  You may as well just use:

```
var list = _context.Entity.ToList<object>();
```

There is no way for you to get any more compile-time support than from using that method.

While you can use reflection to create the list, for example by using:

```
public static IList ToList(this IEnumerable source, string typeName)
{
    return ToList(source, Type.GetType(typeName));
}

public static IList ToList(this IEnumerable source, Type type)
{
    var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(
        typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(type));
    foreach(object item in source) list.Add(item);
    return list;
}
```

The only advantage that you would have using one of these two over the first example is that adding an item to the list that is not of the type specified would throw an exception, as opposed to allowing the list to contain any type of `object`. Usually this isn't important, but it may be better to have the exception right in your face over allowing items that shouldn't exist into the list.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but how can this two extensions solve the issue? They will return newly created **empty** `List` of `typeName` type.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Right, I did the hard part and forgot to add the easy part.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to do this at runtime. See the following post:

[C# generic list <T> how to get the type of T?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)