# How to extract an object name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object, gettype

i've got a class filled with lists of subclasses:

```
public class ClassOfKb
{
    public List<Data> KbDatas {get;set;}
    public List<Product> KbProducts {get;set}
}

public class Data
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public byte[] data {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class Product
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public byte[] Image {get;set;}
}
```

i create an object:

```
ClassOfKb kb = new ClassOfKb
```

now i'd like to extract the string "Datas" from the sub-object kb.KbDatas, I tried:

```
string name = kb.KbDatas.GetType().BaseType.Name.Substring(2);
```

aswell as:

```
string name = kb.KbDatas.GetType().Name.Substring(2);
```

but nothing gave me what I need, is there any way to do this?

EDIT: to specify my question, the string I need is the name of the list, except the first two letters! KbDatas => Datas

EDIT2: i did a mistake, the list-names and class-names are different and i need the list-name

Comment: I don't see a string called 'Data'. Your question discusses 'Data', your code implies you're trying to work with the 'Name'. Please clarify.

Comment: see my edit: i'd like to get a part of the name of my list

Comment: calling `kb.KbData.GetType()` to get a property type can make side effect by calling that property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Type.GetGenericArguments` to solve this

```
       ClassOfKb kb=new ClassOfKb();
      kb.KbData = new List<Data>();
      string nameOfData = Type.GetType(kb.KbData.ToString()).GetGenericArguments().Single().Name;
```

**OUTPUT :** nameOfData  = Data

```
      kb.KbProduct = new List<Product>();
      string nameOfProduct = Type.GetType(kb.KbProduct.ToString()).GetGenericArguments().Single().Name;
```

**OUTPUT :** nameOfProduct  = Product

Comment: works, but not as i wanted it, perhaps my question was misleading, i edited it, any idea how to extract the list-name with a function as simple as your first?

Answer (score 0):

Since that's a collection it is likely that there are multiple `Data` objects in it, each with a name. You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) to concat them with a separator:

```
string names = string.Join(",", kb.KbData.Select(d => d.Name));
```

If there's just one object you don't get a comma at the end. If there's no object you get an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

erm, since you have a `List` of `Data` there will be a sequence of `Name`s.

```
IEnumerable<string> names = kb.KbData.Select(d => d.Name);
```

maybe you want just the first one?

```
string firstName = kb.KbData.First(d => d.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
string name = kb.KbData[0].Name.Substring(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of what you've written, you're looking to get the name of the type in the List instance KbData?

If so, I think this may be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043778/775479

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the name of the property.  There are several methods for doing so.

Get the name of the generic argument from the property itself - If you know the name of the property.

```
ClassOfKb kb = new ClassOfKb()
   { KbData = new List<Data>(), KbProduct = new List<Product>() };
Console.WriteLine(kb.KbData.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].Name);
```

Get the name of the property from reflection, if you know the data type of the property.

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = kb.GetType()
           .GetProperties()
           .FirstOrDefault(p=>p.PropertyType == typeof(List<Data>));
Console.WriteLine(pi.Name.Substring(2)); // ignoring the kb prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with reflection. This is example without any checks - just show the mechanism:

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfo = typeof(ClassOfKb).GetProperty("KbData");
Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
Type genericArgument = propertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
string name = genericArgument.Name;
```

Because property `KbData` is generic `List<Data>` you need ask for generic arguments of property type: `propertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]` and you should test if the type is really generic by `genericArgument.IsGenericType` and check generic arguments count

Comment: so it seems there is no way to archieve this with an automatic methode where i can pass several lists to get the string (without specifying the name in GetProperty() manualy, which is the outcome i expect)

Comment: you can use `typeof(ClassOfKb).GetProperties()` to retrieve all properties and filter them as you need. Then simply foreach all expected properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the property name than you can use Expression.
The code below define function for extract name prom a property:

```
public string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> property)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

This converts property to property name string:

```
GetPropertyName(()=>k.KbDatas).Substring(2)
```