# C# reflection check that FieldType is some list

Tags: c#, reflection

Is it possible to specify that `test` is `List<>` without specifing in condition type of `List<int>`?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SuperClass1 class1 = new SuperClass1();
            PrintAllFields(class1);
        }

        public static void PrintAllFields(object obj)
        {
            var SuperClassType = obj.GetType();
            foreach (var item in SuperClassType.GetFields())
            {
                if (item.FieldType == typeof(List<>))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it's List");
                }
                else if (item.FieldType == typeof(Int32))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it's int32");
                }
                else if (item.FieldType == typeof(Byte))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it's byte");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class SuperClass1
    {
        public int param1;
        public int param2;
        public int param3;
        public byte param4;
        public List<int> test;
        public SuperClass1()
        {
            test = new List<int>();
        }

    }
}
```

**Update:** 
I used function from related answer, now code look's like. And it does not work correct. I expected to get in console message `Console.WriteLine("it's List");` but it seems that i something doing wrong. How to fix this problem? Because i think this problem is different from problem in related question.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SuperClass1 class1 = new SuperClass1();
            PrintAllFields(class1);
        }

        public static void PrintAllFields(object obj)
        {
            var SuperClassType = obj.GetType();
            foreach (var item in SuperClassType.GetFields())
            {
                if (IsInstanceOfGenericType(typeof(List<>), item))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it's List");
                }
                else if (item.FieldType == typeof(Int32))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it's int32");
                }
                else if (item.FieldType == typeof(Byte))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("it's byte");
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool IsInstanceOfGenericType(Type genericType, object instance)
        {
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            while (type != null)
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType &&
                    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class SuperClass1
    {
        public List<int> test = new List<int>();
        public SuperClass1()
        {
            test = new List<int>();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this sound similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t)

Comment: save list type as a string:    

    string listName = typeof(List<>).ToString();
    listName = listName.Substring(0, listName.Length - 3);//drop [T]

then 

    if(item.ToString().Contains(listName))

Comment: @rmbq: No, don't do that. use the methods in reflection designed for this sort of thing... See the answer here or the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Chris i tried your solution but didn't worked for me... maybe i made something wrong

Comment: @rmbq: well there is a problem with your code then. `type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)` will correctly identify if that type is a generic list. Why isn't it working for you? I don't know, I can't see your code. https://ideone.com/05zNiR will clearly demonstrate the technique is sound though.

Comment: The linked duplicate has some additional very useful information - like checking subclasses and interfaces.

Comment: I'll try again, sorry

Comment: @Chris sorry to bother you again, what i'm doing wrong here? https://ideone.com/iogjBb

Comment: @Chris, I used suggestion from related question. And it does not work correct :(((((

Comment: @A191919 Are you stepping through the code to get some more detailed troubleshooting information?  For example, is your `test` field being returned by `SuperClassType.GetFields()`?  If it is, step into `IsInstanceOfGenericType` and see what is going on that doesn't match your expectations....   (Also, just FYI, there are two Chris's commenting here.  I don't know the other one, but he seems like an okay guy...)

Comment: @A191919 In this case, the object you are passing into `IsInstanceOfGenericType` is a `FieldInfo` object.  Therefore the type you are checking is `FieldInfo` instead of `List<int>`.  I will update my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this as an extension method.

```
    public static bool IsList(this Type type)
    {
        return type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
    }
```

Usage:

```
    if (item.FieldType.IsList())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("it's List");
    }
```

---

To answer your updated question, you are calling this function

```
public static bool IsInstanceOfGenericType(System.Type genericType, object instance)
```

with an instance of `FieldInfo`.   You don't have an instance of `List<int>` at this point in the code.  I think you would be better off changing the code to...

```
if (IsOfGenericType(typeof(List<>), item.FieldType))
{
... etc
...
public static bool IsOfGenericType(System.Type genericType, System.Type type)
...
```