# C# How to turn all empty lists inside object into null

Tags: c#, list, reflection, null

First of all, i'm aware of the popular advice that you should [avoid returning empty lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970001/9555272) at all. But as of now, due to a myriad of reasons, i'm met with no other choice but to do just that.

What i'm asking is how do I **iterate** through the properties of an object (probably through `Reflection`), take whatever lists I may find and check if it's empty. If so, then turn it into `null`, otherwise, leave it be.

I'm stuck with the following code, which includes somewhat of a try with `Reflection`:

```cs
private static void IfEmptyListThenNull<T>(T myObject)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType && propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            //How to know if the list i'm checking is empty, and set its value to null
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample of data and  expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t shows how to check for list... then calling `.Count` property either through `dynamic` or reflection should not be a problem...

Comment: The answer you linked to says “NEVER return null when returning a collection or enumerable. ALWAYS return an empty enumerable/collection ...”; how did you interpret this to mean “avoid returning empty lists”?

Comment: @DourHighArch Talk about euphemisms...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you, just use `GetValue` method and cast value to `IList`, then check for emptiness and set this value via `SetValue` to `null`.

```
private static void IfEmptyListThenNull<T>(T myObject)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType && propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
                {
                    if (((IList)propertyInfo.GetValue(myObject, null)).Count == 0)
                    {
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(myObject, null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```