# How to get the list of properties within list of a class?

Tags: c#, list, class, properties, system.reflection

How do I get a list of all the properties of a class?

```
public class ReqPerson
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Age { get; set; }
    public List<Detail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class Detail
{
    public String Job { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
}
```

This is my code, and the result only get properties class ReqPerson, not for class Detail.

```
 private static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(object obj)
    {
        return obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    }

       ReqPerson req = new ReqPerson();
        // Get property array
        var properties = GetProperties(req);

        foreach (var p in properties)
        {
            string name = p.Name;
            var value = p.GetValue(Inq.ReqInquiry(req, null);
            Response.Write(name);
            Response.Write("</br>");
        }
```

Anybody can improve my code?

Comment: Please show the code you're using to call `GetProperties()`.

Comment: you need to check for a collection type when you arrive at a certain property and if it is a collection you need to iterate over it and get those properties of the elements of this collection

Comment: @MatthewWatson `var properties = GetProperties(object);`

Comment: That couldn't be your *exact* code as `object` is a keyword. I understand that's probably *similar* to your some code that demonstrates the problem, but often the important aspects are in the differences between what you show and what you're running. Please provide a [mcve], and it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: ReqPerson req = new ReqPerson();
            var properties = GetProperties(req);

            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                string name = p.Name;
                var value = p.GetValue(req, null);
                Response.Write(name);
                Response.Write("</br>");
            }

Comment: what about this line: `var value = p.GetValue(req, null)` and `var value = p.GetValue(Inq.ReqInquiry(req, null);` which one is the correct line?

Comment: Can you tell us what you want the output to look like?

Comment: I would almost say that [this is a fitting duplicate candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043778/5174469)

Comment: do you want only the names of alle properties of `Details` ? or do you want also the individual values of each element in you list?

Comment: I think the OP wants a recursive solution that descends through all the elements of a collection property.

Comment: Maybe take a step back and explain what you are trying to do here. For example, what would you expect to happen if a class had a child reference to itself? What would you expect the output to be then? This seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @MatthewWatson "I think the OP wants a recursive solution that descends through all the elements of a collection property" in this case [this duplicate might fit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20554262/5174469)

Comment: I want the output All properties in ReqPerson class and Details class. Because the result from my code is properties in ReqPerson only.

Comment: you can see this link
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-a-class)

Comment: "output All properties in ReqPerson class and Details class" that would mean basically you want a list with `{ Name, Age, Job, City }` did I understand you correctly? you are not looking for the values of each individual entry in the `List<Details>` ? is that true?

Comment: @MongZhu ya thats rigth. Because My ouput only {Name, Age, Details}.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public virtual ICollection<Detail> Details { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to iterate over the type of Collection. For example

```
private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetProperties(Type type)
{
    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        if ( property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces()
               .Any(x => x == typeof(IList)))
        {
             foreach(var prop in GetProperties(property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
                yield return prop;
        }
        else
        {
            if (property.PropertyType.Assembly == type.Assembly)
            {
                if (property.PropertyType.IsClass)
                {
                    yield return property;
                }
                GetProperties(property.PropertyType);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return property;
            }
        }
    }
}
```