# How do I use reflection to dynamically call a type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, datatable

I have a DataGrid and I need to convert it to a DataTable. The problem is that I need To be able to get the type of my DataSource dynamically. The grid DataSource is of type 'Observable' which is a class I have in my project, but my task is to be able to dynamically create the DataTable without needing to specify the type only using the DataSource. How can I generate a method that I can use to place in `<T>` without getting the error " 'mytype' is a variable but is used like a type" .

```
Type mytype = Grid_Job.DataSource.GetType();

DataTable dt = CreateDataTable<mytype>((IEnumerable<mytype>)Grid_Job.DataSource);

public static DataTable CreateDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            Type type = typeof(T);
            var properties = type.GetProperties();

            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
            }

            foreach (T entity in list)
            {
                object[] values = new object[properties.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(entity);
                }

                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }

            return dataTable;
        }
```

My Observable class is

```
public class Observable 
{
    public int JobNo { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public string Job_Type { get; set; }
    public string Job_Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `Observable` class. Does it implement `IEnumerable<T>'?

Comment: yes when I use IEnumerable<Observable > the code works just fine and Type mytype = Grid_Job.DataSource.GetType(); returns "Observable" correctly but I can't use it in the code.

Comment: What are the *actual* types that might be in the `DataSource` here? it matters, because there are a range of ways of doing this, and a few particularly relevant abstractions that need to be used in some cases. So: if you did `Grid_Job.DataSource.GetType()`: what is it?

Comment: so I used  string s = mytype.ToString(); and string s returned literally "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection' 1 [ERP_UI.Job.Observable]" where ERP_UI is the name of my project and Job is the folder containing the class Observable

Comment: and myType.Name returns "Observable"

Comment: k, that type doesn't implement any of the abstractions I had in mind, so that means you need to look for the `T` via reflection; there are some options here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043755/c-sharp-generic-list-t-how-to-get-the-type-of-t

Comment: again same problem with the code provided in the link...I get the type in a variable but I can't insert it to the list CreateDataTable<itemType>((IEnumerable<itemType>)Grid_Job.DataSource); I can't use the type I get to generate a list of this type....

Comment: @NourMawla agreed; then *just don't* - your method doesn't need to be generic - posting an answer that shows this

Comment: Note that in `CreateDataTable<T>` you are not using generic type `T` for anything useful. You can just make method non-generic and accept `Type type` argument instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effectively, you need to discard the generics and think in terms of the collection at runtime - discovering the element type itself. For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Reflection;

static class P
{
    static object GetData()
        => new ObservableCollection<Observable>
        {
            new Observable { JobName = "abc", JobNo = 123 },
            new Observable { JobName = "def", JobNo = 456 },
            new Observable { JobName = "ghi", JobNo = 789 },
        };
    static void Main()
    {
        // note that we don't know *anything* about the data source here
        object dataSource = GetData();
        DataTable dt = CreateDataTable((IEnumerable)dataSource);

        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            Console.Write(col.ColumnName);
            Console.Write("\t");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
            {
                Console.Write(row[col]);
                Console.Write("\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static DataTable CreateDataTable(IEnumerable list)
    {
        Type type = GetElementType(list.GetType());
        var properties = type.GetProperties();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in properties)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(info.PropertyType) ?? info.PropertyType));
        }

        object[] values = new object[properties.Length];
        foreach (object entity in list)
        {   
            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
            {
                values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(entity);
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
    static Type GetElementType(Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type interfaceType in type.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (interfaceType.IsGenericType &&
                interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                == typeof(IList<>))
            {
                return  type.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
public class Observable
{
    public int JobNo { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public string Job_Type { get; set; }
    public string Job_Status { get; set; }
}
```

Note that *in some cases* you should prefer the `TypeDescriptor` model over reflection, as this allows runtime definition of properties; this is a niche area and *probably* doesn't apply to you, but it relevant to know about. As an example, this is how `DataTable` itself chooses to expose the properties it has as discoverable at runtime to general purpose tools. There are also a few list indirection APIs that need to be considered in those cases.